# PHP: Wating for JSON to load completly before decoding it

Tags: php, json, parsing

I´m requesting an API like so (Domain is NSFW):

```
$external_videoid = "ph57fbb82bd33ab";

$string = file_get_contents("http://www.pornhub.com/webmasters/video_by_id?id=".$external_videoid."&thumbsize=big");
$json = json_decode($string, true);

$title = $json["video"]["title"];
echo $string;
```

But I can´t retrieve any data. $title is empty. The echo gives me:

```
<html><head>[...]<bodyonload="go()">Loading...</body>[...]</html>
```

Which might indicate that the JSON I want to retrieve is somehow loading, I guess. Seems pretty clear to me. It seems like file_get_contents has to wait for the site to load. What can I do?

APPEND: Sometimes the request works. Sometimes it doesn´t.

Comment: I think "loading..." IS the title :). What is the result of print_r($json); ?

Comment: print_r($json) is NULL. What do you mean by loading is the title? The title is empty. "<html><head>[...]<bodyonload="go()">Loading...</body>[...]</html>" is the content of the "json" I want to decode.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, $title echos as:

I Feel Myself Creature Comforts 1

(lol)

I suppose the connection was ACTUALLY loading when you tried it. The json returns some highly "entertaining" information haha, especially the tags (NSFW obviously)

Be aware pornhub has an API(!): http://www.hubtraffic.com/

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, sometimes it works. But not even 60% of the time. Have you tried it several times?

Comment: Never heard before that a json file can be "entertaining" :D ...mm weird.

Comment: I am really not sure anything can be done to "wait" for the external site :(

Comment: Maybe with curl? But I tried - not a quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
$v= "ph57fbb82bd33ab";
$url="http://www.example.com/sample/param?id=".$v;
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$characters=json_decode($data, true);
echo $characters['video']['title'];
```